# For a metric space $(M,d)$, how is $d : M \times M \mapsto [0,\infty]$ an into function?

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

**Question**

For a metric space $(M,d)$, how is $d : M \times M \mapsto [0,\infty]$ an into function?

The book I am reading says that it is (with a metric defined in the usual way). Specifically, it says

> > Let $M$ be a set. A *metric* on $M$ is a function $d$ from $M \times M$ into $[0,\infty]$.

The definition of an into function says that if $f(x_1)=f(x_2),$ then $x_1=x_2$. Consider $(\mathbb{R^2},d)$ with the Euclidean metric. Then, since $d$ is an into function, if any two pairs of points $p$ and $q$ have the property $d(p)=d(q)$, then $p=q.$ If $$p=[(x_{p_1},y_{p_1}),(x_{p_2},y_{p_2})]$$ and $$q=[(x_{q_1},y_{q_1}),(x_{q_2},y_{q_2})]$$

Then we would have $x_{p_1}=x_{q_1}$, $y_{p_1}=y_{q_1}$, and so on. But if we interpret the distance between two points in $\mathbb{R^2}$ as the length of the line segment between the points, then clearly we can "rotate" the line, preserving the distance while altering the points. This seems to contradict the fact the $d$ is an into function.

Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: The metric in general is not an "into" function.

Comment: The $f$ you describe above is one-to-one. Saying $f$ is a map from $X$ into $Y$ just means that for each $x\in X$, we have $f(x) \in Y$.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the phrasing that the book used. I have edited my question to include a quote from the book.

Comment: I don't really understand your notation $[(x_{p_1}, y_{p_1}), (x_{p_2}, y_{p_2})]$, but yes, metrics are not injective in general.  Any circle is a counterexample to that (and a circle is basically what you described with your rotated line segment).  But some metrics, such as the Euclidean metric are *onto* the interval $[0,+\infty)$.  Note the $)$ and not $]$ on the $+\infty$.  Note that "into" doesn't really mean "injective" or at least that's not a widely used synonym.

Comment: Ah, so "into" does not mean "one-to-one" or "injective" in this case. Don't some authors use "into" to mean "one-to-one"?

Comment: As I said above, I don't think the book is using "into" to mean "one-to-one"; you're intuition is right: a metric is not one-to-one. I don't think I've seen into used that way, but it certainly may have happened.

Comment: @tilper I use that notation because $p$ is a member of $\mathbb{R^2} \times \mathbb{R^2}$, so it is an ordered pair of points in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: Ah, got it.  The square brackets were throwing me off.  May be better to stick with $()$ or, since $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2$ really is just $\Bbb R^4$, use $(x_{p_1}, y_{p_1}, x_{p_2}, y_{p_2})$.

Comment: @tilper That's an interesting point. I agree, but I also interpret the two notations differently. One is two points in "two-space" and the other is a single point in "four-space." What's going on with that? Are they really the same?

Comment: Maybe "isomorphic" may have been a better word if you're familiar with the concept from abstract algebra. It depends on the application I guess. Also it looks like you're using $d$ for two different things in your post. If $d$ is the metric in $(\Bbb R^2, d)$ then you'll need a different name for the function that you apply to elements of $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2$.  For example, if $p = (a,b)$ and $q = (c,d)$ are both in $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2$ then we could define $s(p,q) = (d(a,b), d(c,d))$. But using $d$ for the metric on both $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2$ isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a false problem, vacuous hair-splitting caused by a slightly careless use of the preposition "into": here it expresses the fact that $d(x,y)$ lives "in(side)" $[0, \infty]$, in other words the pairs $(x,y)$ of $M \times M$ are taken by $d$ "into" the interval $[0, \infty]$ (where the preposition is used as in the common daily casual language, not in some mathematical way). A non-ambiguous definition should have dropped the preposition and should have said: *"a metric on $M$ is a function $d : M \times M \to [0, \infty]$ such that etc."* (As a side note, the interesting thing here is not "into", but rather the fact that $d$ is allowed to take the value $\infty$ which is not the usual choice.)